# PL/SQL Trying to display tableID as another tables Name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am making an NHL oracle sql database. I am trying to create a SELECT query where it shows the homeTeam from game table but is displays the teamName from the team table. Essentially I want the output to 'SELECT hometeam, homescore, awayteam, awayscore' but instead of showing the teamID's I want to see the teamNames in the homeTeam and awayTeam columns. I believe this can be done with Joins just not able to get it working.

```
create table team (
  teamID        number(2,0) not null,
  teamAbb       varchar2(3),
  teamName      varchar2(20),
  location      varchar2(20),
  division      varchar2(20),
  conference    varchar2(20),
  constraint pk_team primary key (teamID)
);

create table game(
 gameID     number(2,0) not null,
 gameDate   date,
 homeTeam   number(2,0),
 homeScore  number(2,0),
 awayTeam   number(2,0),
 awayScore  number(2,0),
 constraint pk_game primary key (gameID),
 constraint fk_homeTeam foreign key (homeTeam) references team (teamID),
 constraint fk_awayTeam foreign key (awayTeam) references team (teamID)
);
```

With these inserted

```
DECLARE

BEGIN

insert into team values(10, 'ANA', 'Ducks', 'Anaheim', 'Pacific', 'Western');
insert into team values(11, 'ARI', 'Coyotes', 'Arizona', 'Pacific', 'Western');
insert into team values(12, 'BOS', 'Bruins ', 'Boston', 'Atlantic', 'Eastern');
insert into team values(13, 'BUF', 'Sabers ', 'Buffalo', 'Atlantic', 'Eastern');

COMMIT;

END;

DECLARE

BEGIN

insert into game values (1, to_date('01-11-2020','mm-dd-yyyy'), 10, 2, 11, 1);
insert into game values (2, to_date('01-13-2020','mm-dd-yyyy'), 11, 5, 12, 6);
insert into game values (3, to_date('03-04-2020','mm-dd-yyyy'), 10, null, 13, null);

COMMIT;

END;
```

This is what I am seeing currently with my SELECT[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to perform 2 joins with the teams table

**Query**

```
select t1.teamName AS HomeTeam, g.homeScore, t2.teamName AS AwayTeam, g.awayScore
from    game g
    inner join team t1 ON t1.teamID = g.homeTeam
    inner join team t2 ON t2.teamID = g.awayTeam
```

**Result**

```
HomeTeam    HomeScore    AwayTeam   AwayScore
---------------------------------------------
Ducks       2            Coyotes    1
Coyotes     5            Bruins     6
Ducks       NULL         Sabers     NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want two joins:

```
select th.teamname as hometeam, g.homescore,
       ta.teamname as awayteam, g.awayscore
from games g join
     teams th
     on g.hometeam = th.teamid join
     teams ta
     on g.awayteam = ta.teamid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
select t.teamName "Home team"
       , homescore "Home score"
       , (select teamname from team where teamID = g.awayTeam) "Away team"
       , awayscore "Away score"
from team t 
join game g
on t.teamid = g.hometeam;
```

P.S: You can also add aliases to your columns (Aliases are the names of the columns 
 that will be shown in a result)

[Here you can see a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=16fee50c4b59e6d12c28bb37ed62b7ac)

When sport result is in question you can also show it like this:

```
select t.teamName || '-' ||(select teamname from team where teamID = g.awayTeam) "HOME - AWAY"
       , NVL(homescore, 0) || ':' || NVL(awayscore,0) "SCORE"
from team t 
join game g
on t.teamid = g.hometeam
```

Where you will concatenate the team names and results and with `NVL` NULL values will be turned into `0` in a result.

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=19d8980ca9785b1336c2d60ba5c1faad) for that option.